# A function with IVP has continuity

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a function with the Intermediate value Property.Let $x\in \mathbb R$.Suppose to each sequence $x_n\rightarrow x,\exists M>0 $ such that $|f(x)-f(x_m)|\leq M\sup |f(x_n)-f(x_m)|$

show that $f$ is continuous.

Solution:Using sequential criteria ;let $x_n$ be a sequence such that $x_n\rightarrow x$  to show $f(x_n)\rightarrow f(x)$  .enough to show that $f(x_n)$ is cauchy.

Any help to show that

Answer (score 0):

Assume $f$ is not continuous at $x$. Then there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $\delta>0$ there exists $\xi$ with $|\xi-x|<\delta$ and $|f(x)-f(\xi)|>\epsilon$. From this, we find a sequence $\xi_n\to x$ with $|f(\xi_n)-f(x)|>\epsilon$. By considering a subsequence we may assume that the sign of $f(\xi_n)-f(x)$ is always the same, wlog. $f(\xi_n)>f(x)+\epsilon$ for all $n$. By the IVP, we find $x_n$ between $\xi_n$ and $x$ with $f(x_n)=f(x)+\epsilon$. Of course also $x_n\to x$. We thus arrive at the contradiction
$$0<\epsilon=|f(x)-f(x_m)|\le M\sup|f(x_n)-f(x_m)|=0.$$
Hence $f$ is continuous at $x$.

Comment: Why is $\sup|f(x_n)-f(x_m)|$=0? Can u please explain?